# Android how to put listview in view pager fragments

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have implemented a swipey tabs app using viewpager by using this template in Eclipse
[image]

Now i get an activity which extends FragmentActivity like this

```
        package com.example.abcd2;

    import java.util.Locale;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        /**
         * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
         * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
         * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
         * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
         * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
         * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
         */
        SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

        /**
         * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
         */
        ViewPager mViewPager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
            // primary sections of the app.
            mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                    getSupportFragmentManager());

            // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
         * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
         */
        public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

            public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
                // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
                // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
                if(position==0)
{
Fragment frag2=new ShowFrag2();
                return frag2;}
else
{
Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;}
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // Show 3 total pages.
                return 3;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        /**
         * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
         * displays dummy text.
         */
        public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
            /**
             * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
             * fragment.
             */
            public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

            public DummySectionFragment() {
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                        container, false);
                TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                        .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                        ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
                return rootView;
            }
        }

    }
```

In this, to create a new fragment in one of the tabs, i use if-else based on position in the getItem() method as shown. 
The fragment showfrag2 is  this

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ShowFrag2 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2, container, false);
    }
}
```

My question is, how do i create a listview in one of this fragments . I would like to use a simple listview only in this manner

```
LevelAdapter adapter = new LevelAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_item, weather_data);


    listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);



    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But this has been done in an activity. How can i use something like this in the fragment above. Also, i cannot use ListFragment as the getView() method is returning a fragment. 
Please help regarding how to implement this. 
Thanks 
EDIT:
Here is my adapter code :

```
    package com.example.abcd3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LevelAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Level> {

     static Context context;
        static int layoutResourceId;   
        static Level data[] = null;

    /*    public LevelAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Level[] data) {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
        }*/

        public LevelAdapter(ShowFrag1 showFrag1, int listItem,
                Level[] weather_data) {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;

            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            WeatherHolder holder = null;

            if(row == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

                holder = new WeatherHolder();
                holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
                holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
               // holder.imgIcon2=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon2);


                row.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
            }

            Level weather = data[position];
            holder.txtTitle.setText(weather.title);
            holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(weather.icon);

            return row;
        }

        static class WeatherHolder
        {
            ImageView imgIcon;
            TextView txtTitle;
        //    ImageView imgIcon2;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have `ListView` defined in `R.layout.frag2` and set the adapter to listview in `onCreateView` of `ShowFrag2`.  (Similar to the way its done in activity)

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View fragmentLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2, container, false);

    ListView listView1 = (ListView) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.mylistview);

    LevelAdapter adapter = new LevelAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, weather_data);
    listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

    return fragmentLayout;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the findviewbyid() and getlistview() functions do not come up in the list of available function if I try what you said in fragment. Can you post some example code if possible?

Comment: Added a example, you can follow it. I have not tested it, but you get the idea

Comment: i am getting a null pointer exception in the line inflater line even though i have defined the XML file and also in the line where we create an object of the adapter.

Comment: please check the updated question. i have added the code for my adapter which is giving null pointer exception. I am also getting error in the line where we create an object of the adapter if I remove "static" from the adapter's code. where is the mistake? I am getting nullpointerexception:storage==null

Comment: i think the issue is with the constructor being incompatible with fragments. How do i rectify that?

Comment: no. i have fixed that issue . instead of `LevelAdapter adapter = new LevelAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_item, weather_data);
` it should be `LevelAdapter adapter = new LevelAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.list_item, weather_data);`

Comment: can you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149039/viewpager-recyclerview-issue