# Android TabView with listview, how to show changed content when the an activity is loaded via tabedview

Tags: android, listview, tabview

i am implementing android tabed view with list view as shown in this tutorial,

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

suppose my tabs are like this vieweditems and unvieweditems, where i am loading files as listitems. so when i click on vieweditems and selected an entry from the listview, i can view the items, then i press back i will again get the tabview. but here the file which i viewed again is also present there.

And i am loading the files from the sdcard which is in a specified folder.

look at mycode

```
public class MainPageEBook extends TabActivity {
// TabSpec Names
private static final String Unviewed_SPEC = "Unviewed";
private static final String Viewed_SPEC = "viewed";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_tab);
     System.out.println("hesredsjncs");
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // unviewed Tab
    TabSpec inboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(Unviewed_SPEC);
    // Tab Icon
    inboxSpec.setIndicator(Encrypted_SPEC);
    Intent inboxIntent = new Intent(this, UnviewedFiles.class);
    // Tab Content
    inboxSpec.setContent(inboxIntent);// loads the viewed files when pressed back
   // startActivity(inboxIntent);// if i give this i wont get tabed view

    // viewed Tab
    TabSpec outboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(Viewed_SPEC);
    outboxSpec.setIndicator(Viewed_SPEC);
    Intent outboxIntent = new Intent(this, ViewedFiles.class);
    outboxSpec.setContent(outboxIntent);
    //startActivity(outboxIntent);

    // Profile Tab

    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(inboxSpec); // Adding Inbox tab
    tabHost.addTab(outboxSpec); // Adding Outbox tab
 }
}
```

i have a filter function so that in the activity UnviewedFiles, the files which are already viewed wont be shown.

my logic is like this all the files will be in a folder say unviewed, when i click on a file it will be copied to viewed folder.

in my filter function i am taking the names of all files in both folders to string arrays viewedstring[] and unviewedstring[]. i compare both of them a create a new array with strings which are present in unviewdstring[] but abscent in viewedstring[]. this function is writted UnviewedFiles.java.

so when i call

```
inboxSpec.setContent(inboxIntent);
```

only the previous view is loaded, i want the updated list view. how to do it?

please help

Comment: best practice is to use viewpager with fragment adapter

Comment: but my activities a listviews, can it be done with fragment adapter? is there a tutorial for this? any links please?

Comment: yes you can listview inside each of your fragment

Comment: @AmrutBidri i used listview in fragment and implemented the same, but what i needed is not working. i mean the listview is not updating

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17642515/1576416

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20677719/1576416